# How Force textbox to just accept numbers between 2.1 to 9.5

Tags: c#, winforms

in C# and windows form application,

I have some textbox that i want to force user to only can enter Number and just a specific number for example in this case my number range is {2.1, 2.2, ..., 9.4, 9.5}

this is how i force textbox to just accept numbers:

```
    private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!((int)e.KeyChar>=48 && (int)e.KeyChar<= 57 || (int)e.KeyChar ==8))
        {
            e.KeyChar = (char)27;
        }
    }
```

but I don't know how set a range for it: like only between {2.1 to 9.5} or {25 to 91}

Comment: post your attempt based on one of the previous answers that you found. Then we can help you correct any mistakes you made.

Comment: Please also be very specific with your requirements.  Is this winforms, wpf, asp-mvc, (etc)?  Do you want to prevent the entry of invalid information completely?  Or just show some error for invalid data?

Comment: What subsystem is it? Forms I assume?

Comment: Please link the question you tried the solution from, what issues you had when you tried it yourself and your code.

Comment: @CathalMF I edited my question

Comment: @ryanyuyu sorry for asking confusing question, i  want to prevent the entry of invalid information completely.

Comment: Use a MaskedTextBox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For WinForms, just use a [NumericUpDown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Drop it on your form, set the `Minimum`, `Maximum`, `DecimalPlaces` and `Increment` parameters to your liking and job done.

Access the value via the control's [`.Value`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.value%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property.

[image: NumericUpDown]

Answer (score 0):

Add a regexvalidator control for the textbox and use a regular expression within that to ensure only the numbers you require can be entered.
I don't know the regex offhand but it should be easy enough.

Something like -

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ValidationExpression="Expression Goes Here" ControlToValidate="YourControl" ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="RegularExpressionValidator"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Comment: In fact, a range validator might be even easier.